# Upgrading to new version of Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, upgrade, system-installation

i recently have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, then I notice that Ubuntu will release newer LTS version very soon. I have dual boot between Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 7, but what if I upgrading my Ubuntu to new version  does it:

1. erase my Windows 7 os?
2. make me to download new update like I'm installing fresh Ubuntu OS?
3. does it erase my data (Music, picture, etc etc) inside my Ubuntu or Windows 7?

Sorry for a very 'unacknowledged' question about it, I am very new to Ubuntu, I just want to know. Some information will help me a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't lose anything but make sure you back first (both Windows and Ubuntu) more information here [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)